# As an independent/non-affiliated researcher, what would I replace a logo with on a business card?

Tags: independent-researcher, early-career, business-card

I'm currently not affiliated with any academic institution; but - I still get around, interact and need some business cards.

The thing is, without any institutional information, a card tends to look kind of empty if it just has your name, address, email, and phone (and maybe your website).

Also, having an institute/company logo gives the business card a basic color scheme to work with, and anchors to position elements "against".

What would be a useful replacement - content-wise or design-wise - for an institute/company logo?

Comment: Was about to write a similar answer with photo... But reverse side may contain your topic(s) of research?

Comment: @SolarMike: I was asking about the primary side. Reverse side is a whole other kettle of fish!

Comment: Well, hope it goes well anyway.

Comment: Consider affiliating with the Ronin Institute: http://ronininstitute.org/ They supply a logo you could use

Answer (score 2):

I have seen plenty of business cards, even for real businesses that do not use logos and graphics and just contain text. However, some are distinctive by the use of coloured card, and other features.

I have also seen personal cards that contain a photo in place of an icon or logo. Really useful to assist contact to remember who the card came from.

Its all about design and function really.

Comment: For example, none of these (extremely classy) business cards have any logos:  https://youtu.be/cISYzA36-ZY?t=84